# Change start, end lineString coordinate order in geoJson file

Tags: python, geojson

I have a .geojson file with many lineStrings with the location of transects used to monitor shoreline change, so each transect runs across a land/water boundary. When visualized as is, the transects originate offshore and end onshore. For an analysis tool I am using, I need the locations to be swapped: the first coordinate needs to start on land and end offshore. I will have many thousands of these transects to change and want to make sure I'm doing it correctly but can't seem to figure out this very simple task (sorry, I am new here). I am working in python and earth engine.

```
# original
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "EastChukci_small_testArea",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": 2722 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -17592698.71288351342082, 11344741.029055444523692 ], [ -17592054.347651835530996, 11343198.733621645718813 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": 2723 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -17592838.831736516207457, 11344682.393273767083883 ], [ -17592194.440066188573837, 11343140.124529516324401 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": 2724 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -17592978.948162343353033, 11344623.755085829645395 ], [ -17592334.530055023729801, 11343081.513031836599112 ] ] } },
]
}

# desired
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "EastChukci_small_testArea",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": 2722 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[ -17592054.347651835530996, 11343198.733621645718813 ],  [ -17592698.71288351342082, 11344741.029055444523692 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": 2723 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -17592194.440066188573837, 11343140.124529516324401 ], [ -17592838.831736516207457, 11344682.393273767083883 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": 2724 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -17592334.530055023729801, 11343081.513031836599112 ] ], [ -17592978.948162343353033, 11344623.755085829645395 ] ] } },
]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read and write a json file you can use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module. The code below should solve your problem, but the downside of it is that it loads the whole file to the memory at once.

```py
import json

with open('data.json', 'r') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

for feature_data in data['features']:
    feature_data['geometry']['coordinates'].reverse()

with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(data, json_file)
```

Comment: Thank you! So simple, works great.